# SQL Server CE - Unable to insert values in the BIT column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce-3.5

I have created a small table in SQL Server CE 3.5

Following is the table description:

```
ROW_ID NVARCHAR(30),
NAME NVARCHAR(30),
TEST BIT
```

I am using following query to insert record in the table:

```
insert into EMP(ROW_ID, NAME, TEST)
values('123', 'XYZ', TRUE);
```

But I am getting a strange error:

> Error Message: The column name is not valid. [Node Name (if any) = ,Column name = TRUE]

Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instead of `true` and `false` use `1` and `0`. Eg:

```
insert into EMP(ROW_ID, NAME, TEST)
values('123','XYZ',1);
```

This is for [SQL Server 2005 `bit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

> The string values TRUE and FALSE can be converted to bit values: TRUE is converted to 1 and FALSE is converted to 0.

You can try it. If it applies to CE following code (`'TRUE'` as string) might work as well:

```
insert into EMP(ROW_ID, NAME, TEST)
values('123','XYZ', 'TRUE');
```

Answer (score 4):

Nothing strange about that. It's saying is doesn't know what TRUE is. Not a known name, not a column in the table, hence error message.

Use 1 for true, 0 for false.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise You Can try this way:

```
  insert into EMP(ROW_ID, NAME, TEST)
  values('123','XYZ',b1);    // b for bit type and 1 is the field value as (true)

or

  insert into EMP(ROW_ID, NAME, TEST)
  values('123','XYZ',0b1);   // 0b for bit type and 1 is the field value as (true)
```